# android thread: how worker thread send signal to main(GUI) thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a gui thread starting a new thread to do some busy things. The GUI thread will wait the worker thread to be completed, in the mean time the GUI need to be responsive.

Psedo code:

main thread:

start_thread();
wait_thread_done();

work thread:

doing_sth();
notify_main_thread();

What is the easiest way to do this in android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with Android's AsyncTask.  The documentation is here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

And you can call Activity.runOnUiThread() to update the UI from your background task.

Answer (score 1):

A small working snippet :

```
new Thread() {

                    public void run() {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try{
                                        // **Do the GUI work here**

                                } catch (Exception e) { }
                        }});
                            };

            }.start();
```

Comment: I would recommend using AsyncTask instead of thread whenever possible.  And it is the 'easiest' way to do this.

Comment: Yes, but you can't do AsyncTask inline.

Comment: You can use them inline the same way you did with your Thread.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: and why would that be?

Comment: how would would change this snippet to send a value from worker thread to main thread?

Comment: Personally I prefer not using AsyncTask, which is a convenience convention. Easier is not always better.

Answer (score 0):

Call Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable), the Runnable you pass to that method will execute on the GUI thread.

Or use an AsyncTask - which is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

waiting for result will make gui thread unresponsive. you need to use AsyncTask and override onPostExecute to perform operation required when background thread is done